# golang concurrent write to uint64 variable with same values?

Tags: go, concurrency

```
type simpleTx struct {
    gas uint64
}

func (tx *simpleTx) UpdateGas() {
    tx.gas = 125
}

func TestUpdateGas(t *testing.T) {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(100)

    tx := &simpleTx{}
    for i:=0; i <100; i++ {
        go func(t *simpleTx)() {
            tx.UpdateGas()
            wg.Done()
        }(tx)
    }

    wg.Wait()
}
```

Above test prints out "WARNING:DATA RACE" when run with `-race` option.
Is there any type in golang that can be used for concurrent write with same values?
Do I need to always use mutex or atomic variable?

Comment: *Is there any type in golang that can be used for concurrent write with same values?* No. *Do I need to always use mutex or atomic variable?* Yes.

Comment: Concurrent write to the same value is undefined behaviour. It may help to learn about [`sync.Once`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#Once), which allows you to call the same function multiple times, but have it only execute once.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, There are many Go idioms to use - to prevent data race - and **one should not write to a variable concurrently** (or concurrent read and write) without proper synchronization:

0. For your special case - writing the same value. Using `sync.Once`:

```
type simpleTx struct {
    sync.Once
    gas uint64
}
func (tx *simpleTx) UpdateGas() {
    tx.Do(func() { tx.gas = 125 })
}
```

1. Using `atomic.StoreUint64` for atomic write:

```
atomic.StoreUint64(&tx.gas, 125)
```

2. Using `sync.Mutex`:

```
type simpleTx struct {
    sync.Mutex
    gas uint64
}

func (tx *simpleTx) UpdateGas() {
    tx.Lock()
    tx.gas = 125
    tx.Unlock()
}
```

3. Using a channel:

```
type simpleTx struct {
    gas chan uint64
}
func (tx *simpleTx) UpdateGas() {
    select {
    case tx.gas <- 125:
    default:
    }
}
func TestUpdateGas(t *testing.T) {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    tx := &simpleTx{make(chan uint64, 1)}
    for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func(t *simpleTx) {
            tx.UpdateGas()
            wg.Done()
        }(tx)
    }
    wg.Wait()
}
```